# JDBC driver not available for 'org.postgresql.Driver' on Spring Roo

Tags: spring-roo

I am trying to use `database reverse engineer`... See full Roo v1.3 script and UBUNTU env at [this simple "hello" script](https://github.com/ppKrauss/dummy-java-spring/blob/master/roo1/hello3pg.md).

The error:

```
Located add-ons that may offer this JDBC driver
2 found, sorted by rank; T = trusted developer; R = Roo 1.3 compatible
ID T R DESCRIPTION -------------------------------------------------------------
01 Y Y 9.1.0.901-1_0001 Postgres #jdbcdriver...
02 Y Y 9.1.0.901_0001 Postgres #jdbcdriver...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[HINT] use 'addon info id --searchResultId ..' to see details about a search result
[HINT] use 'addon install id --searchResultId ..' to install a specific search result, or
[HINT] use 'addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName TAB' to install a specific add-on version
JDBC driver not available for 'org.postgresql.Driver'
```

---

### NOTES

This is a variation of the [spring.io/spring-roo](http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/#running-from-shell) fast guide 10 lines example. Very simple...

It was after (and work fine) project and database Roo initializations,

```
project --topLevelPackage   com.testRoo1Hello2pg
jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database POSTGRES --databaseName hello2db --userName postgresql --password postgres
```

The database.properties seems:

```
database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
database.url=jdbc\:postgresql\://localhost\:5432/hello2db
database.username=postgresql
database.password=postgres

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

The command that fails is:

`database reverse engineer --schema public --includeTables "test1"`

See [roo1/hello3pg.md](https://github.com/ppKrauss/dummy-java-spring/blob/master/roo1/hello3pg.md) for more details.

Comment: See also simple "how to install driver" question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/41190520/287948

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message that the Spring Roo shell is showing you is not an error. Let's check it:

```
Located add-ons that may offer this JDBC driver
2 found, sorted by rank; T = trusted developer; R = Roo 1.3 compatible
ID T R DESCRIPTION -------------------------------------------------------------
01 Y Y 9.1.0.901-1_0001 Postgres #jdbcdriver...
02 Y Y 9.1.0.901_0001 Postgres #jdbcdriver...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[HINT] use 'addon info id --searchResultId ..' to see details about a search result
[HINT] use 'addon install id --searchResultId ..' to install a specific search result, or
[HINT] use 'addon install bundle --bundleSymbolicName TAB' to install a specific add-on version
JDBC driver not available for 'org.postgresql.Driver'
```

This message appears after execute the `database reverse engineer --schema public --includeTables "test1"` commands.

Spring Roo is trying to connect Postgres database but.. oh oh... there's not exists a JDBC Driver for the Postgres database deployed in the OSGi context (remember that Spring Roo works under OSGi environment), so it's not possible to connect with the DB.

Spring Roo shell is offering you some options to resolve the problem above. So, if your read the message, you could check that you are able to use the following command to install the Postgres JDBC driver into the OSGi context.

```
addon install bundle --searchResultId 01
```

(01 id is the number under the ID column)

After execute the command to install the OSGi bundle, try to execute the reverse engineer command again.

That should work!

Hope it helps,

**NOTE**: If you are interested in know more about OSGi and the Apache Felix implementation you could read http://felix.apache.org/ and https://www.osgi.org/developer/specifications/

Comment: Thanks @jcgarcia, now it is working!  The use of HINT is not very friendly, is error prone... I can report  problems at  [github.com/spring-roo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-roo) but there are no `/issues` enabled.  Well, now is working but is not working 100% as expected: I not see constraints (as  "DEFAULT 99", "NOT NULL" or "CHECK") neither the fields declaration at *Table*.java* generated codes.

Comment: Ops, for readers (and also for jcgarcia):   the command that installed was `addon install id --searchResultId 01`  not `install bundle` ... And I have problems with `install bundle`, no adicional installation was performed.

Answer (score 1):

I tried both

```
addon install bundle --searchResultId 01
```

and

```
addon install bundle --searchResultId 02
```

and was still getting the no driver found message `JDBC driver not available for 'org.postgresql.Driver'`.

What did work for me was to install the previous version of the bundle.

```
osgi install --url  http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release/org/springframework/roo/wrapping/org.springframework.roo.wrapping.postgresql-jdbc3/9.0.801.0001/org.springframework.roo.wrapping.postgresql-jdbc3-9.0.801.0001.jar
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4 running on a docker container.