# JDBC driver not available for 'org.postgresql.Driver' for Spring Roo

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot

**How do I obtain a JDBC driver for JAVA Spring 'org.postgresql.Driver'?**

- I am using terminal UBUNTU 16 LTS
- I am using Oracle Java8, Spring v4, Spring boot
- my project [is Spring Roo, see this question for more error-details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41189702/287948)

---

Perhaps [clues for answer are here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13867021/287948), but

- Where is the .jar file, what to download? it is from https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html ??
- Where do I put it? rename it? is to obtain /usr/local/pgsql/share/java/postgresql.jar ??
- How do I say to UBUNTU 16 LTS that postgresql.jar exist? There's no command to create CLASSPATH or PATH_TO_TOMCAT\lib?  How to do it in the terminal, step-by-step?

I need a "dummy" answer to see step-by-step, in the UBUNTU terminal, the solution.

Comment: Are you using the embedded Tomcat server provided by Spring Boot ?

Comment: @davidxxx *yes*, embedded Tomcat server provided by Spring Boot (and supposing the same at Spring Roo)

Comment: Ok. I just wrote the answer. Let me know if something is missing for you.

Answer (score 0):

I've just answer your question in

[JDBC driver not available for 'org.postgresql.Driver' on Spring Roo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41189702/jdbc-driver-not-available-for-org-postgresql-driver-on-spring-roo/41199193#41199193)

The problem is that you need to deploy the JDBC driver into the Spring Roo shell, not in your system.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Please flag the question as a duplicate if you think it's the same